# Externalize strings for Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any Eclipse plugin that takes strings from code and puts them in strings.xml? I found "Externalize strings" function in Eclipse, but I don't know how to get it to work with strings.xml.

Comment: That'd be amazingly useful wouldn't it? I can't seem to break the habit of writing strings in Java and then manually moving them to resources much later on... a tool to automate this would be very handy indeed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use Refactor in Eclipse:

- highlight the string
- From the Eclipse menu select **Refactor -> Android -> Extract Android String**.

The string will be moved to strings.xml and the call to `getContext().getString(R.string.my_string)` generated.

Comment: Can't find Android in Refactor menu. I use Eclipse Galileo version: 1.2.2.20100216-1730 with ADT plugin Version: 8.0.1.v201012062107-82219

Comment: Works on Eclipse SDK 3.5.2 and ADT 8.0.1

Comment: I tried to find it in context menu, now i found it in Eclipse menu. Thanks.

Comment: you can also use, alt+shift+a,s

Comment: still i am not able to see this Android in refactor dialog.

Comment: The fastest way is **`CTRL + 1`** while string is selected ;)

Comment: `String will be moved to strings.xml and the call getContext().getString(R.string.my_string) generated.` - it doesn't work that way, unfortunately (at least not for me). The conversion leaves the literal string as `R.string.my_string`, causing a type mismatch.

Comment: This may be a regression in ADT.

Comment: @Ewoks `CTRL + 1` is my favourite feature of Eclipse and any IDE ever!

Comment: You can also use Shift+Alt+A, S

Comment: @KonradMorawski: are you calling the refactoring from a class that extends Context ?

Comment: Shift+Alt+A, S - that's broken in newer versions of eclipse - you have to press Shift+Alt+A, then select the refactoring with the mouse - DUH

Answer (score 5):

You can also position your cursor over the string literal and press ctrl+1. Then choose "externalize" by the android icon.

Credits:
[Do externalized strings need to be in strings.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637896/do-externalized-strings-need-to-be-in-strings-xml)

Answer (score 0):

use shortcut **Alt+Shift+A** and after that press **S**. it'll solve your problem.