# Android: is there an easy way to find all the Strings in my project?

Tags: android, string, localization

I want to scan my Android project for all hardcoded Strings so I can localize the project, putting the Strings in strings.xml. I see an option in Eclipse to 'Externalize Strings...' but it isn't specific to Android.

I know [you can refactor individual strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527136/externalize-strings-for-android-project) but I'd like to refactor all the Strings at once. I've got a ton of files, and I'm trying to avoid going through each one manually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would just open up a terminal window(putty if you are on windows) at the root directory of your project.  You can then run something like the following:

```
grep -r --include=*.java '="[^"\r\n]*"' ./*  --to look for something like this String test="text";, a string with =""
or
grep -r --include=*.java '"[^"\r\n]*"' ./*  -- to look for any string, anything enclosed in ""
```

Of course the next part is to actually substitute the Strings into the Strings.xml, that could be scripted out as well, but may take more tinkering.

Comment: You could also just do this from within Eclipse.  Choose Search->File.  Then paste "[^"\r\n]*" in the text field and make sure "Regular expression" is checked.  The search results are better organized this way.

Comment: rplankenhorn's suggestion works well in androidstudio also. cmd+shft+f and select "regular expression"

Comment: I got this: 
zsh: no matches found: --include=*.java

Comment: @RobertYiJiang my guess is it has to do with using wildcards in zsh, take a look here http://superuser.com/questions/584249/using-wildcards-in-commands-with-zsh

Comment: I got it on my Mac: grep -r --include="*.java" '"[^"\r\n]*"' ./src > ./strings.txt

Answer (score 7):

I was searching for this myself. There is a nice way of doing this:

Right click on "src" directory -> Source -> Externalize Strings

This will find all Non-Externalize Strings and let you Externalize them.

Hope this will help :)

**Edit:**
This is not same as the Android -> Extract Android String.
But it can help you find all the Non-Externalize strings. Then, on each string you will have to perform: 
Ctrl + 1 -> Android -> Extract Android String.

Answer (score 1):

`Field[] fields = R.string.class.getDeclaredFields(); // or Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
    String str = "";
    for (int  i =0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(fields[i].getName(), "string", getPackageName());
        str += fields[i].getName() + " = ";
        if (resId != 0) {
            str += getResources().getString(resId);
        }
        str += "\n";
    }`

You will get all codes of strings with its values in "str" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure eclipse to show all the string in code:
[Configuring eclipse to complain for hard coded strings for android xml preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755216/configuring-eclipse-to-complain-for-hard-coded-strings-for-android-xml-preferenc)

And replace them one by one with eclipse refactor

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This solutions can help with HALF your problem- finding all hardcoded strings. You will still need to do the actual refactoring yourself because you still need to ***name*** all extracted strings.

---

#### EDIT:

This is the **shorter** and **better** answer:

1. Menu -> Analyze -> Run Inspection by name... (even has a shortcut if you feel nimble)
2. Type "Hardcoded Text", select scope and run.

---

You can run a custom **lint** inspections - to find only hardcoded texts in layout files:

1. Menu -> Analyze -> Inspect Code
2. selects desired scope (layouts, for instance)

   [image]
3. under 'Inspection profile', select a new custom profile (...)
4. Duplicate an existing profile, and un-check all inspections EXCEPT 'HardcodedText'

[image]

[image]

5. Run this inspection, and all your hardcoded strings will conveniently be collected into a single list.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the [Google CodePro](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=google%20code%20pro%20eclipse) addon for Eclipse has this feature in there *somewhere*

Comment: there is nothing there that I found that help with this issue