# Configuring eclipse to complain for hard coded strings for android xml preferences

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, preferences

In my android proj I want eclipse to treat all hard coded strings in the xml files as error.
So what I have done is changed Window->Preferences->Android->Lint Error Checking to Error.

Now it seems to point at all the hard coded string in the layout files as errors but misses the preferences file.

How can I apply same rule for preferences file.

Thank you,

Comment: Error/Warning detection in Android XML files is an ADT feature. So if you can't find it through ADT options in Eclipse, you'd need a custom plugin to handle what you are wanting.

Comment: @jason  the feature is available on ADT options in Eclipse

Comment: @PedroTeran It's available for layout files, but I don't think it's available for other XML files.

Answer (score 3):

at the end of the list  on Window->Preferences->Android->Lint Error Checking  there is a preference that is called internationalisation, there is the preference you want to change

[image]