# Eclipse plugin for hardcoded text in Android

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, hardcode

Is there any plugin for Eclipse (like in IntelliJ) for extracting all hard-coded strings into strings.xml file?

Comment: I think this question was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025010/android-is-there-an-easy-way-to-find-all-the-strings-in-my-project

Comment: Not really. I'm looking for a tool to to automatically move all hardcoded strings to strings.xml and replace with proper variables.