# Do externalized strings need to be in strings.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

When I right-click on my project in Eclipse, and select "Externalize Strings" the wizard ends up putting the strings in a new "messges.properties" file; shouldn't it go in /res/values/strings.xml, or does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Externalize Strings" is a standard functionality that is implemented in eclipse to work with java. If you want to extract Android string you should simply select the string, press ctrl+1 and in the appeared menu choose "Extract String" with the Android picture near this option.