# How to extract all String from all Java files in a Java project?

Tags: java, string, embedded-resource

I need to extract all `hard coded Strings` values from all `Java` files in a `Java project`
Into a `Java Constant file`

for example

> **Input**

```
// Java file number 1
public class A {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HardCoded String A");
    }
}

// Java file number 2
public class B {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HardCoded String B");
    }
}
```

> **Output**

```
// a Java Constant file
public class MyConstants {  
    public static final String HardCodedString_01 = "HardCoded String A";
    public static final String HardCodedString_02 = "HardCoded String B";   
}

// Java file number 1
public class A {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyConstants.HardCodedString_01);
    }
}

// Java file number 2
public class B {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyConstants.HardCodedString_01);
    }
}
```

I am aware of **Externalize Strings for Eclipse**
[image]
BUT it works over **one file** not **all files**

And when i check this post
[Extract all string from a java project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/160382/1824361)
I could not find the link of provided presentation

Also i check this post
[Externalize strings for Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4527136/1824361)
But that is provided for `Android` projects not `Java` projects

Comment: always when declaring your constant variable make sure they are all Capsed for instance:     public static final String HARDCORESTRING_01 = "HardCoded String A"; f

Comment: @яша nice comment to meet `Java` standards but any answer for the core question :)

Comment: Try [Lingobit Extractor](http://www.lingobit.com/extractor/java_extract_hardcoded_string.html). While I haven't tried it, and it is proprietary software, the free trial may (or may not) solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First to inspect all hard coded Strings values from all using `Eclipse`
The core idea is that
`The Regular Expression` of **Java hard coded String value** is `"*"`
So
We can do that Using search by this criteria
For example

Eclipse Search Inquiry
[image]

Eclipse Search Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Might be a over-engineered solution, but give a try to sonarqube which can give you static analysis of code and much more than just hard-coded string values.

If you are looking for a code to do that, you can try linux commandline (e.g. grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern") solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
We can use Java Code also.We need to pass the directory name as below 
and it will give the File name and matched Line which contains the Hard Code   
String ( " <Hard Code String in Double Quotes> " ) .
```

Directory/Path :  c:\User\XYZ\src\

[image: Logs Sample]

Code :

```
                import java.io.BufferedReader;
                import java.io.File;
                import java.io.FileReader;
                import java.io.IOException;
                import java.util.List;
                import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
                import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;
                import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

                public class ScanFiles {

                    private static final Logger logger = ScanFilesLogger.getLogger(ScanFiles.class);

                    private static void searchFiles(String folderPath, String searchString) throws IOException {
                        File folder = new File(folderPath);
                        List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(folder, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
                        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                             File[] fList = folder.listFiles();
                             for (File file : files) {
                                 if (!file.canRead()) {
                                    file.setReadable(true);
                                    }
                                    String content = "";
                                    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));) {
                                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                        String line = br.readLine();
                                        logger.info("File :::::  " + file.getName());
                                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                                        {
                                        // Below condition we can omit in the search condition //
                                        if (line.contains(searchString) && (!line.contains("System.out.println") && !line.contains("logger.info") && !line.contains("Logger.info") && !line.contains("logger.debug") && !line.contains("Logger.debug") && !line.contains("logger.error") && !line.contains("Logger.error")  && !line.contains("Logger.info") && !line.contains("logger.debug") && !line.contains("Logger.debug") && !line.contains("logger.error") 
                                                     && !line.contains("LOGGER.debug")  && !line.contains("LOGGER.info")  && !line.contains("LOGGER.error") && !line.contains("assertTrue") && !line.contains("//") && !line.contains("/*")))
                                            {

                                                logger.info("Matched Line :::::"+line);
                                            }                           
                                        }
                                    } 
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Not a Directory!");
                        }
                     }
                    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

                        if(args.length == 0)            
                        {
                            logger.info(" ::::::::::  PATH cannot be empty ::::::::::");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }           
                            searchFiles(new File(args[0]).getAbsolutePath(),"\"");

                    }
                }
```