# Convert android project to multi-language

Tags: android, eclipse, multilingual

I have an Android project that I developed one year ago. I didn't think in do the project multi-language and now I need support it.

There are any easy way to detect all strings and generate the XML file? Or I need modify the project string for string?

The project is developed in Eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a multilingual android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259128/how-can-i-create-a-multilingual-android-application)

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, I knew Android support it and how create it. But I need some way to detect the strings in the project and convert in resources strings to do the application multilenguaje.

Comment: As far as I understand you have to set each string you want to be multilanguage as a "String object" such as `R.string.my_string_name` or `@string/my_string_name` as @Frank N. Stein points. I dont think that there is some other way. Intenationalization eclipse plugins for example seem to follow the same approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK You need to modify the strings in your project manually. If you have hard-coded strings in your layouts then you can use Lint to find out all the hard-coded strings. Put them then into values/strings and the translation should go to the respective folder of each language.

EDIT:

If you're running Eclipse you can use the search feature to help you track all your hard-coded String. Check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733282/how-to-extract-all-string-from-all-java-files-in-a-java-project)

Comment: Lint solve me the strings in XML files, but I have strings in the code too, and the tool don't detect it.

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a very simple way to localize apps: string resources.

You need to provide several strings.xml files.
Each in a directory called `/res/values-xy`, where xy is the language (i.e.: `es`, `fr`, `en`, `de`, `it`, ...).

Then just refer these strings in your project, like `R.string.my_string_name` (in Java) or `@string/my_string_name` (in xml)

For reference: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

**[EDIT]**

Same goes for arrays: just use `/res/values-xy/arrays.xml`

---

Note: the names `strings.xml` and `arrays.xml` are just `conventional` ones can be changed to anything you like better.